# What do the ASCII characters preceding a carriage return represent in a PDF page?

Tags: pdf, encoding

This is probably a rather basic question, but I'm having a bit of trouble figuring it out, and it might be useful for future visitors.

I want to get at the raw data inside a PDF file, and I've managed to decode a page using the Python library [`PyPDF2`](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) with the following commands:

```
import PyPDF2
with open('My PDF.pdf', 'rb') as infile:
    mypdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(infile)
    raw_data = mypdf.getPage(1).getContents().getData()
    print(raw_data)
```

Looking at the raw data provided, I have began to suspect that ASCII characters preceding carriage returns are significant: *every* carriage return that I've seen is preceded with one. It seems like they might be some kind of token identifier. I've already figured out that `/RelativeColorimetric` is associated with the sequence `ri\r`. I'm currently looking through the [PDF 1.7 standard Adobe provides](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), and I *know* an explanation is in there somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it yet in that 756 page behemoth of a document

Comment: Tip: Change your last line to `print(raw_data.decode('latin1'))` to get a somewhat better view, instead of the `b` string it returns now.

Comment: @usr2564301 Decoded strings don't seem to work probably because of the carriage returns resetting everything to the beginning of the line during the attempted display; I'm fine with the binary string format anyway, because the I can process them further when needed. But if I did use that suggestion, I would probably tweak it to replace `\r` in the output string with something else.

Comment: You are right! I got `\n`s from the PDF I tried, but I can see how `\r` line endings would mess up your display. Good luck with your investigations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defining thing here is not that `\r` – it is just inserted instead of a regular space for readability – but the fact that `ri` *is an operator*.

A PDF content stream uses a stack based Polish notation syntax: `value1 value2 ... valuen operator`

The full syntax of your `ri`, for example, is explained in Table 57 on p.127:

> *intent*  **ri** *(PDF 1.1)* Set the colour rendering intent in the graphics state (see 8.6.5.8, "Rendering Intents").

and the idea is that this indeed appears in this order inside a content stream. (... I tried to find an appropriate example of your `ri` in use but cannot find one; not even any in the ISO PDF itself that you referred to.)

A random stream snippet from elsewhere:

```
q
  /CS0 cs
  1 1 1 scn
  1.5 i
  /GS1 gs
  0 -85.0500031 -14.7640076 0 287.0200043 344.026001 cm
  BX
  /Sh0 sh
  EX
Q
```

(the indentation comes courtesy of my own PDF reader) shows *operands* (`/CS0`, `1 1 1`, `1.5` etc.), with the *operators* (`cs`, `scn`, `i` etc.) at the end of each line for clarity.

This is explained in **7.8.2 Content Streams**:

> ...
>   A content stream, after decoding with any specified filters, shall be interpreted according to the PDF syntax rules described in 7.2, "Lexical Conventions." It consists of PDF objects denoting operands and operators. **The operands needed by an operator shall precede it in the stream.** See EXAMPLE 4 in 7.4, "Filters," for an example of a content stream.
>   (my emphasis)

**7.2.2 Character Set** specifies that inside a content stream, whitespace characters such as tab, newline, and carriage return, are just that: separators, and may occur anywhere and in any number (>= 1) between operands and operators. It mentions

> NOTE The examples in this standard use a convention that arranges tokens into lines. However, the examples’ use of white space for indentation is purely for clarity of exposition and need not be included in practical use.

– to which I can add that *most* PDF creating software indeed attempts to delimit 'lines' consisting of an operands-operator sequence with returns.

Comment: Is there any place I can get a complete list of these operators? I've seen the various sections (8.4.4 - Graphics State Operators, 8.6.8 - Color Operators, and 9.3 - Text State Parameters and Operators), but some of the operators are not defined in any of those sections, like `g`.

Comment: Using searching for "operator", I seem to have found what I was looking for in the ISO standard: Table 51 on page 111 lists the operator categories.

Comment: @Graham: `g` is defined in **8.6.8 Colour Operators** (Table 74). I find the ISO specification dry as a bone to read and parse; perhaps you want to read Adobe's own [PDF Reference, 3rd Ed.](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf) (direct link to the PDF) as it is much more palatable.

Comment: @Graham: a further tip if you want a 'readable' content stream such as in my snippet. You can easily recognize strings, arrays, names (`/Stuff`), and numbers, and put it on a single line. Then, the next item that is *not* one of these must be the operator.